# Conditions on $f(\lambda):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$ to have $a_n\approx n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Assume the real non-negative function $f(\lambda):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$. For the simple case that the function fulfills $f(\lambda)=\lambda$ for all $\lambda\geq0$, it follows that $a_n = n$.

Now assume $f$ only fulfills this condition approximately, $\lambda(1-\delta)\leq f(\lambda) \leq \lambda(1+\delta)$ for all $\lambda\geq0$ and for some $0 < \delta\ll1 $. 
Given some $\varepsilon<1$, how $\delta$ needs to be chosen and which additional conditions on $f$ are necessary to have $n(1-\varepsilon) \leq a_n \leq n(1+\varepsilon)$ for all $n\geq0$ ?